# How to properly pass params to an object using form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to make an API which passes the filled form symbols, new.html.erb, to an object in another view, using form_for and params[], show.html.erb, that shows a post with the filled form, but I can't find the right way, or the best way to do it, something goes wrong when I try to pass the params to the other view

**views/recipes/new.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for :recipe, url: recipes_show_path do |r| %>
 Título: <%= r.text_field :title%><br />
 Tipo da Receita: <%= r.text_field :recipe_type%><br />
 Cozinha: <%= r.text_field :cuisine %><br />
 Dificuldade: <%= r.text_field :dificulty %><br />
 Tempo de Preparo: <%= r.text_field :cook_time_min %><br />
 Ingredientes: <%= r.text_field :ingredients %><br />
 Como Preparar: <%= r.text_field :cook_method %><br />
 Enviar: <%= r.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

**views/recipes/show.html.erb**

```
<h3>Detalhes</h3>
<p><%= @recipe.recipe_type %></p>
<p><%= @recipe.cuisine %></p>
<p><%= @recipe.difficulty %></p>
<p><%= @recipe.cook_time_min %></p>
<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<p><%= @recipe.ingredients %></p>
<h3>Como Preparar</h3>
<p><%= @recipe.cook_method %></p>

<%= link_to 'Voltar', root_path %>
```

**recipes_controller.rb**

```
 class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end
  def new
  recipe = Recipe.new
  recipe.title = [:title]
  recipe.recipe_type = [:recipe_type]
  recipe.cuisine = [:cuisine]
  recipe.difficulty = [:difficult]
  recipe.cook_time_min = [:cook_time_min]
  recipe.ingredients = [:ingredients]
  recipe.cook_method = [:cook_method]
  recipe.save
  
  redirect recipes/show
  end
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'recipes/show'
  get 'recipes/new'
  root to: 'recipes#index'
  resources :recipes
end
```

Comment: Your controller has no `create` method, is that correct?  Can you show the method responsible for actually saving the data?  It looks like your URL is the show method, but you aren't saving anything there, why not just use the conventions rails sets up in place of whatever it is you are trying to do here?

Comment: *something goes wrong when I try to pass the params to the other view*. Can you show what you tried that failed? I don't see anything in your code above that is attempting to pass any params.

Comment: Just edited for better formatting your question, what I've tried first was that, trying to make an object and passing for the other view but it did not work, and since passing de param[:] looks more a clever way to do it only once, since there will be another implementations I would rather implement it, but I do not know how to pass the params to the other view

Comment: Ok so now you are saving it in the `new` view but you are not submitting the form to the `new` method as a post.  Again, why not use the conventions Rails sets up and understand them first before you try something outside that?  I think you do not understand that you submit the form to the method that saves it, usually, a `create` method, and then redirect on save to the `show` method (or wherever).  The `new` method just shows the form for the new object, it doesn't save it.  You are tyring to use the `new` method for two different purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you have to do

First adjust your `new` method

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
end
```

Now build out a `create` method to handle saving the data.

```
def create
  recipe = Recipe.new <-- I think you will need this with this set up
  recipe.title = params[:recipe][:title]
  recipe.recipe_type = params[:recipe][:recipe_type]
  recipe.cuisine = params[:recipe][:cuisine]
  recipe.difficulty = params[:recipe][:difficult]
  recipe.cook_time_min = params[:recipe][:cook_time_min]
  recipe.ingredients = params[:recipe][:ingredients]
  recipe.cook_method = params[:recipe][:cook_method]
  if recipe.save
    redirect_to recipe
  else
    # Probably some error handling?
  end
end
```

Change where the form submits to (the variable has to match what is set in the `new` method so it submits to the `create` method, saves the data and then redirects to the show method.

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |r| %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use symbols with `form_for`. This feature has repeatedly been flagged for depreciation and is not recommended, instead pass an actual variable.

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

Avoid explicitly adding a URL to the form - if you embrace convention over configuration you can reuse the same form for the edit/update action.

If what you want is to actually persist the object to the database you would set it up like so:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :recipies, only: [:new, :create, :show]
# get rid of that other junk
```

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /recipies/:id
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /recipies
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  # this action just displays a form
  # GET /recipies/new
  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  # this action handles the form submission and saves the record in the db
  # POST /recipies
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    # don't just assume the input is valid!
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to @recipe # redirects to recipes/:id
    else
      render :new # just renders the view - does not redirect 
    end
  end

  private 
  # this method whitelists the parameters we want to assign
  # if you are copying a hash key by key you're doing it wrong
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(
     :title, :recipe_type, :cuisine, :difficult, 
     :cook_time_min, :ingredients, :cook_method
    )
  end
end
```

What you want to do is really strange. If you really wanted to pass an unpersisted object through a redirect you would have to place all the parameters in the query string:

```
# recipes/show?recipe[title]="Foo"&recipe[recipe_type]="Bar"...
redirect_to(recipe_path(recipe: recipe.attributes))
```

And then extract out all the parameters again on the other end:

```
@recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
```

That's why you render instead of redirecting when a record is invalid. And when you redirect to the new record you just use the id of the record instead of trying to pass all the attributes.

Comment: I would really recommend that you start with some tutorials or a book. You can't learn rails by making stuff up as you go along.

Comment: I know this, but I've entered in a series of challenges and have little time to do so, I've been studying but part of the challenges are kind of outdated so I've been having double the trouble I normally would, but your answer and the other before yours gave me some direction in how to tackle those things, and for that I'm very grateful

Comment: The basic conventions have not really changed that much since at least Rails 2 - if ever. We are still using the same CRUD verbs and methods. The only relatively new thing here really is strong parameters which was introduced in Rails 4.